# Django Unit Testing - How to load once a DB for multiple tests.py files?

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I have a folder named "test" in my Django project.
Inside this folder I have multiple files named "test_xyz.py".

My goal: loading the DB **only once** and share it across all test*.py files.

What I currently do:

```
class OneTestCase(APITestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        '''
        Init database
        '''
        from myapp.init import init_my_db # a python script loading the db

class TwoTestCase(APITestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        '''
        Init database
        '''
        from myapp.init import init_my_db # a python script loading the db

# same goes for each test*.py file...
```

In other words I am reloading the database from scratch for each test*.py file slowing down the testing execution time.

Is there a way to avoid this, loading the database **only one time** and for all the test*.py files?

Answer (score 0):

A pytest fixture with `scope="session"`?